# implement the logic in c++ using python, how?

Tags: python, c++

I want to implement below logic in c++ using python.

```
struct hash_string ///
{
    hash_string() {}

    uint32_t operator ()(const std::string &text) const
    {
        //std::cout << text << std::endl;
        static const uint32_t primes[16] =
        {
            0x01EE5DB9, 0x491408C3, 0x0465FB69, 0x421F0141,
            0x2E7D036B, 0x2D41C7B9, 0x58C0EF0D, 0x7B15A53B,
            0x7C9D3761, 0x5ABB9B0B, 0x24109367, 0x5A5B741F,
            0x6B9F12E9, 0x71BA7809, 0x081F69CD, 0x4D9B740B,
        };

        //std::cout << text.size() << std::endl;
        uint32_t sum = 0;
        for (size_t i = 0; i != text.size(); i ++) {
            sum += primes[i & 15] * (unsigned char)text[i];
            //std::cout << text[i] <<std::endl;
            // std::cout << (unsigned char)text[i] << std::endl;
        }
        return sum;
    }
};
```

python version is like this, which is not completed yet, since I haven't found a way to convert text to unsigned char. So, please help!

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

text = u'连衣裙女韩范'

primes = [0x01EE5DB9, 0x491408C3, 0x0465FB69, 0x421F0141,
                0x2E7D036B, 0x2D41C7B9, 0x58C0EF0D, 0x7B15A53B,
                0x7C9D3761, 0x5ABB9B0B, 0x24109367, 0x5A5B741F,
                0x6B9F12E9, 0x71BA7809, 0x081F69CD, 0x4D9B740B]

//*text[i] does not work (of course), but how to mimic the logic above
rand = [primes[i & 15]***text[i]** for i in range(len(text))]

print rand

sum_agg = sum(rand)

print sum_agg
```

Take text=u'连衣裙女韩范' for example, c++ version returns 18 for text.size() and sum is 2422173716, while, in python, I don't know how to make it 18.

The equality of text size is essential, as a start at least.

Comment: I think Python already has built-in good-enough hashing of strings. Have you checked that?

Comment: You're probably looking for [`ord`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#ord).

Comment: that's true, it is just that this logic is used universally in our application that I simply need to duplicate it to generate the same hash code. And my code is implemented in python all the way, so I just want to convert it to python for simplicity.

Comment: You can't encrypt text, only bytes. Encode the text first.

Comment: @SanderDeDycker I updated the post, ord doesnot solve it since text.size() in c++ returns 18, while using ord, I cannot get 18.

Comment: @phoenixbai : `text.size()` corresponds to `len(text)`, while `(unsigned char)text[i]` corresponds (somewhat) to `ord(text[i])`

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams not follow, could you be specific?!

Comment: @phoenixbai : or maybe your confusion is caused by the fact that you've put a unicode string in a `std::string`, and expect the length of the `std::string` to be the number of code points rather than the number of `char`s (ie. bytes).

Comment: @SanderDeDycker indexing `std::string` and `ord` are two different things. On python 2 this will fail as text is a unicode object and ord will throw an exception when given non-ascii characters. On python 3 this will produce incorrect results as `ord` returns the unicode code point, but `std::string` is a series of bytes not unicode characters.

Comment: @Dunes : I know `ord` will return the unicode code point (and not just in Python 3, but also Python 2 btw), which is why I used the word "somewhat" to qualify the correspondence with C++. I didn't realize until now that the OP wanted to generate the exact same hashes as in C++ for all encodings.

Comment: @SanderDeDycker My mistake. I must have been thinking of `chr`.

Answer (score 2):

Because you are using unicode, for an exact reproduction you will need to turn `text` in a series of bytes (chars in c++).

```
bytes_ = text.encode("utf8") 
# when iterated over this will yield ints (in python 3)
# or single character strings in python 2
```

You should use more pythonic idioms for iterating over a pair of sequences

```
pairs = zip(bytes_, primes)
```

What if `bytes_` is longer than primes? Use [`itertools.cycle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle)

```
from itertools import cycle
pairs = zip(bytes_, cycle(primes))
```

All together:

```
from itertools import cycle

text = u'连衣裙女韩范'

primes = [0x01EE5DB9, 0x491408C3, 0x0465FB69, 0x421F0141,
                0x2E7D036B, 0x2D41C7B9, 0x58C0EF0D, 0x7B15A53B,
                0x7C9D3761, 0x5ABB9B0B, 0x24109367, 0x5A5B741F,
                0x6B9F12E9, 0x71BA7809, 0x081F69CD, 0x4D9B740B]

# if python 3
rand = [byte * prime for byte, prime in zip(text.encode("utf8"), cycle(primes))]
# else if python 2 (use ord to convert single character string to int)
rand = [ord(byte) * prime for byte, prime in zip(text.encode("utf8"), cycle(primes))]
hash_ = sum(rand)
```

Comment: it is throwing error and I print the bytes_, it is printing endlessly! could you help debug it?

Comment: Sorry, the answer I posted was intended for python 3. I've made an edit to show what to do in python 2.